# Read Permission user cannot access SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, administration, user-information-list

I have granted the permission for user as a Read in SharePoint Online but when user tries to access the URL it shows Access Denied. And I have deleted the user from group and added back still same issue.

After research found that we have to remove user from UIL's and add back to SharePoint. And what I was wondering is how can I reach to page.

And below article says to use with PowerShell but before that I need to see or check how to check the user profile in SharePoint Online not SP admin center.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/03/update-user-email-address-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

[image]

Comment: Have you given read access to one page only? or did you add this user to readers group?

Comment: Added user to SP group (read level) to site

Comment: I have found the solution for it, by reaching it to url _layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0 and deleting user and re-adding back to the SharePoint site collection would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

User Information List is hidden and there's no direct link provided by Microsoft to access this list in a site.

In SharePoint, you can access the User Information List by using URL in below format:

```
siteUrl/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx
```

---

You can enter the URL in browser to access the list directly.

- `https://SiteURL/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx` - Get detailed information for users
- `https://SiteURL/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx` - Get basic information for users

**Reference**: [Everything You Need To Know About User Information List In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/everything-you-need-to-know-about-user-information-list-in-sharepoint)

Comment: But why user is not able to access sharepoint page when read access granted ? and i have checked the above but i cannot check user profile with UIL, if i click on the user name it takes me to delve instead i need to see "User Information"

Comment: Is this happening with all users & or this particular user? Can you check if permissions inheritance is broken for this specific page?

Comment: It is happening only for one user

Comment: No, inheritance was not broken. It is inherited from parent.

Comment: Hi @striker92, is this issue resolved or still facing the issue?

Comment: Problem has been solved